# Pattern for copying hierarchical data from one table to another?

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

Imagine a table with three columns: an ID primary key, a nullable ParentID referencing the ID column on that same table, and a TreeID to indicating the records that make up a particular tree. A basic hierarchical structure might look like this. Note that the ordinal values don't necessarily have an effect on a record's position in the hierarchy.

```
      dbo.TreeNodes             Visual representation:
+----+----------+--------+    --------------------------
| ID | ParentID | TreeID |       Tree 7:     Tree 15:
+----+----------+--------+       1           10
|  1 | NULL     |      7 |       |–3         |–9
|  2 | 4        |      7 |       |–4
|  3 | 1        |      7 |       |–|–2
|  4 | 1        |      7 |       |-5
|  5 | 1        |      7 |
|  9 | 10       |     15 |
| 10 | NULL     |     15 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Given another unrelated table with an identical definition (`dbo.TreeNodes2`, let's say), I've found that copying the data from the first table to the second while maintaining its self-referential hierarchy isn't so straightforward. I get stuck after inserting the new dbo.TreeNodes2 records when it comes time to populate the ParentID values. I would have to have a mapping table of some kind to know which records from the first table map to the new records in the second table. Here's what I've got so far:

```sql
DECLARE @TreeID INT = 7;
-- hard code arbitrary TreeID value for the 2nd table for the sake of demo
DECLARE @NewTreeID INT = 42;

CREATE TABLE #InsertedRows
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TreeNodes2
(
    ParentID,
    TreeID
)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO #InsertedRows
SELECT
    NULL, -- ParentID can't be added yet because the IDs don't yet exist.
          -- They need to be updated in later.
    @NewTreeID
FROM dbo.TreeNodes AS tn1
WHERE tn1.TreeID = @TreeID;
```

I *could* add a non-related `OldID` column to dbo.TreeNodes2 to copy the original IDs to, which I could then use to create a mapping to join on and populate the new ParentID records, then null out all the `OldID` values when I'm done, but this seems like bad design. If SQL Server allowed the OUTPUT clause of an INSERT to include columns from a join, then this would be easy, but [all of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql), as well as my own testing, indicates that only `Inserted.*` columns, `Deleted.*` columns, and scalar values/literals can be used in the OUTPUT clause. Nothing from joins.

My pipe dream, non-valid T-SQL that does what I want would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #InsertedRows
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OldID INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TreeNodes2
(
    ParentID,
    TreeID
)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, tn1.ID INTO #InsertedRows (ID, OldID)
SELECT
    NULL, -- ParentID can't be added yet because the IDs don't yet exist.
          -- They need to be updated in later.
    @NewTreeID
FROM dbo.TreeNodes AS tn1
WHERE tn1.TreeID = @TreeID;
```

From here, I would have a mapping table I can use to populate the ParentID values in the new table.

Is there a pattern for handing these kinds of cross-table hierarchical inserts without relying on an extra column whose only purpose is to allow the migration, after which it's an irrelevant column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario I would not use IDENTITY for primary keys, but switch to sequences.
This way you can reserve sequence numbers to a temporary table, which became your mapping table, something like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TreeNodes2Sequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ; 

CREATE TABLE TreeNodes2 (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR TreeNodes2Sequence),
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE #InsertedRows
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OldID INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #InsertedRows
(
    Id,
    OldId
)
SELECT
    NEXT VALUE FOR TreeNodes2Sequence,
    tn1.ID
FROM dbo.TreeNodes AS tn1
WHERE tn1.TreeID = @TreeID;
```

Then use this temp table to insert all values with null parent and then update parents.

Comment: Wow, I'm so used to using IDENTITY that I never would have thought to use a sequence instead. You're basically using it like a globally accessible IDENTITY counter. Brilliant.